# AWS Cloudfront distro to redirect to s3 static website redirects

Tags: amazon-s3, static, amazon-cloudfront

I have hosted a s3 static website with multiple redirects. Below is the redirect

I am using Cloudfront to backed this website so that I can use https redirection. Lets say the address for the CF is mys3host.com.

Can I use Clodfront so that when I pass https://mys3host.com/AccountA, it redirects accordingly to AccountA, B and so on.

```
   [
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "/AccountA"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "/Bond/AccountA.html"
        }
    },
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "/AccountB"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "/Bond/AccountB.html"
        }
    },
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "/AccountC"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "/Bond/AccountC.html"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: I was able to get the redirection implemented from the cloud front URL to the redirections in the s3 website. However, when they get redirected, it is "http" redirect. I am now looking how we can setup https redirection instead.

Comment: You can also handle the redirect in JavaScript using CloudFront Functions. Here's an example function to redirect a viewer to a country-specific location based on their country, but you can change the conditionals to match your use case. https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-functions/tree/main/redirect-based-on-country

Comment: Thanks. I am actually hosting the static website in s3. There are several html files sitting on the s3 bucket which I wanted to redirect based on the prefix passed to the URL. It is working fine but they are not https ( again since it is hosted on s3).  I am not sure how the java script will be able to do a https redirection unless we create multiple s3 buckets and host multiple static websites and then create a CloudFront for each of the static websites. Still trying to understand..

Comment: If CloudFront is in front of your S3 bucket, that will give you HTTP and HTTPS endpoints. From there, attach a CloudFront Function that looks at the path prefix and rewrites the URL (I misread as a redirect, but you want to rewrite the request CloudFront sends to S3 without changing the public URL). You just need to modify the request.uri. Take a look at this example - you can update the if statement to match your criteria. https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-functions/tree/main/url-rewrite-single-page-apps

Comment: I overlooked. Yes it makes sense and this is what i am going to do. Thanks much.